# C++ JNI open /dev/rtc result invalid argument

Tags: c++

I try to open `/dev/rtc` or `/dev/rtc0` .

```
# ls -l /dev/rtc* 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Aug 11 05:59 /dev/rtc -> rtc0
crw------- 1 root root 248, 0 Aug 11 05:59 /dev/rtc0
```

this is my JNI code (C++):

```
using namespace std; 

void get_system_dt(struct tm tm) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    time_t t = time(NULL);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    tm = *localtime(&t) ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
   
int set_hardware_dt() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    struct tm tm ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    get_system_dt(tm);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    struct rtc_time rt ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    rt.tm_year = tm.tm_year ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    rt.tm_min = tm.tm_mon ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    rt.tm_yday = tm.tm_yday ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    rt.tm_mday = tm.tm_mday ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    rt.tm_hour = tm.tm_hour ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    rt.tm_wday = tm.tm_wday ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    rt.tm_min = tm.tm_min ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    rt.tm_sec = tm.tm_sec ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    rt.tm_isdst = tm.tm_isdst ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    int fd = open ("/dev/rtc0",O_RDONLY); <-- Problem this line                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    cout << fd << endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    if (fd != 3) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
        perror("SET_HW_DT");                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    int r = ioctl(fd,RTC_SET_TIME,&rt);    
    if (r != 0) {
        perror("ioctl");
        return 1;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    }
    close(fd);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    return 0 ;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
} 

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ir_moke_jsysbox_time_JDateTime_syncSystemToHardware (JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz) {                                                                                                                                                      
    int r = set_hardware_dt();                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    if (r != 0) throwException(env,"Failed to sync system to hardware");                                                                                                                                                                                           
}
```

and this output :

```
6
SET_HW_DT: Invalid argument
```

I can not understand why this code result `Invalid argumnt` !
that code with simple main do work without any problem :

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        set_hardware_dt(); 
        return 0;
}

output : 
3
SET_HW_DT: Success
```

What is problem ?

Comment: Your `get_system_dt` does not actually affect the passed-in `tm`. Did you mean to pass in a `struct tm& tm`?

Comment: My problem is line `open ("/dev/rtc0",O_RDONLY);`

Comment: `void get_system_dt(struct tm tm)` -- C++ is not Java.  You are passing `tm` by value, meaning you are changing a temporary variable that gets destroyed as soon as the function exits.  Thus this line: `tm = *localtime(&t) ; ` has no effect on the calling function.

Comment: `struct tm tm ; get_system_dt(tm); ` -- Then after this, `tm` is still uninitialized.  All bets are off as to what happens then.  Unless this: `void get_system_dt(struct tm tm)` is a typo, the solution would seem to be: `void get_system_dt(struct tm& tm)` as already suggested.

Comment: @Botje -- You should post that as an answer.  The code is definitely wrong, and it starts right there.

Comment: why would you assume `fd == 3` ?

Comment: I think success is 3 , that is true ?

Comment: @mah454 [Read the documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/open).  The return value is a non-negative value on success, not specifically `3`.  The code should be checking for `-1`, since that is what is returned when an error occurs.

Comment: oh ! , so why in `main` result 3 is `success` ?! I misunderstood this .

Comment: @mah454 -- Why are you comparing the results from two different programs?  As long as the return value is not `-1`, that's all that matters.  `int main() { int *p = new int; }` and then in another program: `int main() { int *p = new int; }` I would not expect both `p` values to be the same -- C++ does not work this way.  If the function is successful, you use the successful value and be happy with it -- the only thing you can check for is failure, and the documentation clearly states what is a failure value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several problems. From top to bottom:

```
void get_system_dt(struct tm tm)
```

will *never* modify the `tm` you pass in in `set_hardware_dt`. You need to pass a `struct tm& tm` for that code to work.

Next, a typo:

```
rt.tm_min = tm.tm_mon ;
```

Finally, your "problem this line" is not actually the problem.
Instead, this line is:

```
if (fd != 3) {
```

This assumes that the freshly-allocated file descriptor will be number 3. This is typically only the case in small programs that did not open or close any file descriptors before your code runs.

Instead, you should check whether `fd` is negative, as that is the error signal from `open`.